# Adding inline wordpress comment functionality to a non-wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a wordpress.org blog on my website but I do not use the actual blog page to display the blog posts. Initially I tried to style the wordpress blog to match my site, but since wordpress' theme is too constricted I decided to use "the loop" to gather the_author_posts_link, the_title, the_content, etc and display them on my main page. (reference: http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages). The problem I am running into is the comment section. No matter what, I cannot seem to find a way to add comments to my front page using php. I know I can get my post content to display by calling the_content(), but I cannot seem to find a similar function for comments. I'm open to any solution that will allow my pseudo-blog to display comments under each post. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Should be `<?php comments_template(); ?>`. Look in your theme files for that template tag. But it working depends on if you've correctly included the blog header on your non-WP pages.